# function does not exist in pg_proc in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I tried to call my user defined function in pgresql from C# code,

my function creation script is as follows,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."GetUserDailyData"(
    cid integer,
    hid integer,
    currday integer)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  returndata varchar = '';
BEGIN

SELECT data->20+currday into returndata FROM pops
WHERE hybid = hid and cropid = cid;

return returndata;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  COST 100;
```

My method to call this function is as follows,

```
public static object ExecuteScalar(string conString, string spName, NpgsqlParameter[] param)
        {
            using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(conString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
                using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = spName;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    for (var i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter());
                        command.Parameters[i] = param[i];
                    }

                    var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried everything even checked the existence of this function in pg_proc using

```
select * from pg_proc where proname = 'GetUserDailyData'
```

and it reflected the function details row.

But every time it is giving the same error.

Any kind of suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What value of `spName` are you passing to `ExecuteScalar()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding objects with case sensitive names in PostgreSQL can lead to these complications; in this case you need to specify the name of the stored procedure between quotes, however it would be advisable to simply not create any objects that rely on case sensitivity, use underscores instead, or when create/refer to objects using CamelCase without the quotes (which creates/refers to the objects in low-caps). In any case, you may also need to specify the whole interface (not just the name) as the CommandText, and specify the data types of the parameters (see [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/567257.58257.qm@web32006.mail.mud.yahoo.com)).

```
                    ...
                    command.CommandText = "\"" + spName + "\"";
                    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ziggy Crueltyfree Zeitgeister. It worked perfectly now.